# Extremely Slow Querys, after a windows restore point

Tags: performance, mariadb

A few days ago, one of my costumers who has(MariaDB 10.3.10) installed in windows 10, had a power issue on hes computer, after he turned on the computer again, windows pop'd the restore point option for him and he took it, before that, hes data base was working correctly as intended, but after he used the restore point, something happened, and some store procedures, went from 5-10 seconds, to 3-4 minutes.

My first thought was that some tables were corrupted, but afer some test, i decided to make a dump and install the Data in another computer with the same database engine version(MariaDb 10.3.10) and surprisingly, everything worked perfectly, i took the same database, in other 2 different computers, and everything ran correctly, no slow querys nothing, i decided to format the computer with the issue, and installed everything from scratch, but nothing changed, same issues, same problems...

Any thoughts on this=

Comment: Sounds like anti-virus software hogging the disk.

Comment: i thought it was something like that, but the computer literally only have windows installed right now. After we re-installed everything, after of course a format c:

Comment: But if you have Norton (etc) installed, it will be "running".